# FileNotFoundError [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read an Excel file into a Pandas dataframe and plot 2 columns. 
My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pylab import plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')

data1 = pd.read_excel('LogReturns_AAPL.xlsx')
data1[['Returns', 'log_returns']].cumsum().apply(np.exp).plot(figsize=(10, 6))
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

<Figure size 720x432 with 1 Axes>
```

part of the (very long) traceback is as follows:

```
     Error in callback <function install_repl_displayhook.<locals>.post_execute at 0x0000022E1842F158> (for post_execute):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout

      File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

      File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 143, in __init__
        super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

      File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)

      File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
```

Kindly let me know what I should be doing differently. Thank you!

Edit1: The following is the result of `pwd` for the Python script:

```
'C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop'
```

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say the file isn't where you think it is. Try an absolute path, instead of just the filename. Perhaps cd to the directory that contains the file, verify it with `dir`, and put the results of `pwd` in your question, along with the results of `pwd` from the directory in which your script is running.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the message. The file "LogReturns_AAPL.xlsx" is in the same folder as the Python script which is reading it-both are in the Desktop folder. But from the traceback above, I think the "file" being referred to here is the "subprocess.py" file. Any feedback on how to debug this would be great. Thank you! Also here is the result of pwd for the script: 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop'

Comment: Please check file location and its name

Comment: Sir, file location is the Desktop folder for both files (script and xlsx). Name is correct as well. I think the file being referred to here is the subprocess.py file. I have not come across this error before. Kindly advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem is about a file path. Therefore, please try this

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/LogReturns_AAPL.xlsx')
```

This will direct pandas to an absolute path. It might be what you needed.

Comment: Sir, I tried the absolute path as you suggested. But I am still getting the exact same error. Kindly advise. Thanks.

Comment: @trulyrural your problem might be similar to this: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4079

Comment: Sir, I think my issue is actually similar to this one: https://github.com/DavidMStraub/flavio-tutorial/issues/1. I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work. I am still getting the same error. I think the problem is with the subprocess.py file :(